# OpenMDAO version 2.x File Variable Workaround

Tags: python-3.x, openmdao

I'm new to OpenMDAO and started off with the newest version (version 2.3.1 at the time of this post).

I'm working on the setup to a fairly complicated aero-structural optimization using several external codes, specifically NASTRAN and several executables (compiled C++) that post process NASTRAN results.

Ideally I would like to break these down into multiple components to generate my model, run NASTRAN, post process the results, and then extract my objective and constraints from text files.  All of my existing interfaces are through text file inputs and outputs.  According to the GitHub page, the file variable feature that existed in an old version (v1.7.4) has not yet been implemented in version 2.

https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO

Is there a good workaround for this until the feature is added?

So far the best solution I've come up with is to group everything into one large component that maps input variables to final output by running everything instead of multiple smaller components that break up the process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

File variables themselves are no longer implemented in OpenMDAO. They caused a lot of headaches and didn't fundamentally offer useful functionality because they requires serializing the whole file into memory and passing it around as string buffers. The whole process was just duplicative and inefficient, since the files were ultimately getting written and read from disk far more times than were necessary.

In your case since you're setting up an aerostructural problem, you really wouldn't want to use them anyway. You will want to have access to either analytic or at least semi-analytic total derivatives for efficient execution. So what that means is that the boundary of each component must composed of only floating point variables or arrays of floating point variables.

What you want to do is wrap your analysis tools using [ExternalCodeImplicitComp](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.3.1/features/building_blocks/components/external_code_implicit_comp.html), which tells openmdao that the underlying analysis is actually implicit. Then, even if you use finite-differences to compute the partial derivatives you only need to FD across the residual evaluation. For NASTRAN, this might be a bit tricky to set up, since I don't know if it directly exposes the residual evaluation, but if you can get to the stiffness matrix then you should be able to compute it. You'll be rewarded for your efforts with a greatly improved efficiency and accuracy.

Inside each wrapper, you can use the built in [file wrapping tools](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.3.1/other/file_wrap.html) to read through the files that were written and pull out the numerical values, which you then push into the outputs vector. For NASTRAN you might consider using [pyNASTRAN](https://github.com/SteveDoyle2/pyNastran), instead of the file wrapping tools, to save yourself some work.

If you can't expose the residual evaluation, then you can use [ExternalCodeComp](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.3.1/features/building_blocks/components/external_code_comp.html) instead and treat the analysis as if it was explicit. This will make your FD more costly and less accurate, but for linear analyses you should be ok (still not ideal, but better than nothing).

The key idea here is that you're not asking OpenMDAO to pass around file objects. You are wrapping each component with only numerical data at its boundaries. This has the advantage of allowing OpenMDAO's automatic derivatives features to work (even if you use FD to compute the partial derivatives). It also has a secondary advantage that if you (hopefully) graduate to in-memory wrappers for your codes then you won't have to update your models. Only the component's internal code will change.